# Sqlite SQL insert, CSV to CSV data wrangling, How should the query be approached?

Tags: sql, sqlite, csv, csvkit

I'm attempting to insert/wrangle data from one SQLite table to another. Basically my workflow is importing a CSVkit processed CSV into a table named import, creating a new table named export, and then exporting that new table to a fresh CSV.

The only part that I'm not sure about is the SQL part, I've prepared an example dataset.

#### Import

```
Ntype   |Color|Code
:-------|:----|:---
example1|Blue |xyz
example1|Red  |xyx
example2|Black|zyz
example3|Grey |zyz
```

#### Export

```
Name    |Option_Name|Option_Value|Code
:-------|:----------|:-----------|:---
example1|Default    |Default     |
example1|Color      |Blue        |xyz
example1|Color      |Red         |xyx
example2|Default    |Default     |zyz
example3|Default    |Default     |zyz
```

How would this even be approached?  Something using a COUNT function, CASE, GROUP BY?

I'm working from this so far,

```
INSERT INTO export (Name, Option_Name, Option_Value, Code)
  SELECT
    Ntype,
    ???,
    ???,
    Code
  FROM import
```

Just for completeness sake, this is the script I'm working from,

```
#!/bin/sh
## DESCRIPTION: CSV Import, Wrangle, CSV Export

[ -f "$1" ] && {
    FILE="$1"
} || {
    echo "$0 FILE"
    exit 1
}

## Create Temp Dir
T_DIR="$(mktemp tdir.XXXXX)"
trap 'rm -rf $T_DIR' 0 1 2 3 15

## csvtk grep ..., pass pre-processed CSV to STDIN
## But for this quick example I speciifed the filename.
csvtk csv2tab "$FILE" > "$T_DIR/import.tsv"
sqlite3 << EOF
.separator "\t"
.import $T_DIR/import.tsv import

CREATE TABLE export(
    Name  NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    Option_Name   NVARCHAR(255),
    Option_Value   NVARCHAR(255),
    Code    NVARCHAR(255));


## Additional SQL queries

EOF

exit 0
```

Comment: It seems like you're trying to code the CSV file from it's relatively _natural_ form to an [Entity-Attribute-Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) type schema.

Depending on how complicated your real schema is, and how many columns you have etc., you'd perhaps be better served by writing the translation script in a regular programming language.

Comment: Good catch, yea there clearly is a small EAV in there. The problem is though, that this is not representative of the majority of changes required.  It's only for a few columns in a pre-defined set.

Comment: If you don't have any other constraints I'd still go for a Python/JS/Ruby etc. script rather than SQL. Whatever SQL you could come up with - and it'd probably be very specific to SQLite will be very gnarly.

Comment: Gnarly is not really a huge problem in this situation, because this is a wrangle. I can break out and back in, I'm working from an Shell script. Know what, I'm gonna whip up an example of the script also.  To give you the full picture.

Comment: You have not told us what the SQL should do, and I am unable to deduce this from the example data.

Comment: @CL.  import into export .... select.... Updated the question with where I'm at.

Comment: And what is that "???"? Where does the "Default" come from? What is so special about blue and red?

Comment: @CL., "Default"  indicates that it is a place holder line, for an item with variants.  "???" is literally that I have no idea.